# mysql: unable to modify or update column for date value 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql

I have two questions:

1. Why does mysql is not able to notify error when inserting wrong date `0000-00-00` when in the table definition its set to not null..?

example Schema: [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2735ba)

Now if change the duedate to `1970-01-01` it shows error

> > Incorrect date value `0000-00-00` for the column duedate at row1

```
update my_list set duedate = '1970-01-01' where duedate = '0000-00-00';
```

I tried to modify the column but it still shows the same error

```
ALTER TABLE `my_list` modify `duedate` date NULL;
ALTER TABLE  `my_list` MODIFY  `duedate` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01';
```

2. How do I change the duedate to `1970-01-01` for `0000-00-00`;

I got the database from the client so unfortunately work on my.cnf file.

More info:

MYSQL version: 5.5

EDIT: 
This is working

```
update my_list set duedate = '1970-01-01' where id = 16;
```

but not

```
update my_list set duedate = '1970-01-01' where duedate = '0000-00-00';
```

Comment: Since `'0000-00-00'` is not a correct date value you can not use it in your `where` clause. And why do you want it to change to `1970`? `NULL` is the correct value for no date

Comment: it works using `select * from my_list  where duedate = '0000-00-00';`  unfortunately its not working in sqlfiddle but it works in SQL WORK BENCH. I wanted to change to 1970

Comment: do `SET sql_mode = '';` before calling the update query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not enable modify and update date value to '0000-00-00' as a dummy date. because of MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode.

Additionally strict mode has to be enabled for disallowing "zero" values:

**Check version and SQL mode**

```
SELECT version();
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session
```

**Disabling STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode**

you have to disable STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode in mysql config file or by command

By command

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

or

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

if above is not working than go to /etc/mysql/my.cnf (as per ubuntu) and comment out STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

Also, if you want to permanently set the sql mode at server startup then include SET sql_mode='' in my.cnf on Linux. For windows this has to be done in my.ini file.

if above is not working than go to /etc/mysql/my.cnf (as per ubuntu) and comment out STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

Also, if you want to permanently set the sql mode at server startup then include SET sql_mode='' in my.cnf on Linux. For windows this has to be done in my.ini file.

**Note**

MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values, and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode.

**Update Regarding NO_ZERO_DATE**

As of MySQL as of 5.7.4 this mode is deprecated.Refer MySQL 5.7 documentation on NO_ZERO_DATE

Comment: thanks for the explanation but unfortunately i do not have proper rights to the datebase to run `set sql_mode='';`  or modify `my.cnf` file.

Comment: Okay, I have spoken with client today and  iam able to make changes to  my.cnf file and its because sql_mode is set to NULL, the insert statements did not check for null values with `  STRICT_ALL_TABLES  ` i can now make sure that the data is proper and the data will be rejected when inserting wrong data.

Comment: Removing STRICT_TRANS_TABLES  worked for me for a similar problem. Setting up an environment with latest MySQL version turned out to behave very different than a legacy with 5.6. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Cast duedate to string:

```
update my_list set duedate = '1970-01-01' where DATE_FORMAT(duedate, '%Y-%m-%d') = '0000-00-00';
```

Comment: This query works too.. i am able to change the date.. however `why does not the insert statement notify an error when inserting wrong date value but it notifies when using update statement?`

Comment: Even if they are similar, MySql internally performs two distinct operations and probably does not perform the same check.

Comment: Works great. Ty

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
update my_list
set duedate = '1970-01-01' 
where to_days(duedate)IS NULL
```

at least in sqlfiddle

Comment: thanks the above query works and iam able to change the date.. However i still dont get it `why does not the insert statement notify an error when inserting wrong date value but it notifies when using update statement?`